# Java JDBC JTDS test connection string

Tags: java, jdbc, jtds

I have an application using JTDS to connect to SQL Server.  I need to change the database and want to test the connection string first before reconfiguring the application.  I'm a SQL Server DBA, not a Java developer!
Here's my test code:

```
// Import the SQL Server JDBC Driver classes 
import java.sql.*; 
class Example 
{  
   public static void main(String args[]) 
   {  
   try  
   { 
        // Build the connection string, and get a connection 
        System.out.println("1."); 
        System.out.println("2."); 
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://UK-SB-Server:53569;DatabaseName=helpdesk;user=helpdesk;password=MyPwd;Tds=8.0;PrepareSql=3;XaEmulation=false";
        System.out.println("3."); 
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl); 
        System.out.println("Connected."); 

        // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.  
        String SQL = "SELECT * from dbo.AllowedValues";  
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL); 

        // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.  
        while (rs.next())  
        {  
           System.out.println(rs.getString(1) + " " + rs.getString(2));  
        } 
   }  
   catch(Exception e)  
   { 
        System.out.println("Error - " + e.getMessage()); 
        System.exit(0);  
   } 
} 
}
```

I compile it with:

```
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\javac C:\JavaTest\example.java
```

I run it with:

```
C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java -classpath C:\JavaTest Example
```

jtds-1.2.jar and Example.class are both in C:\JavaTest

I get the following error:

```
1.
2.
3.
Error - No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://UK-SB-Server:53569;DatabaseName=helpdesk;user=helpdesk;password=MyPwd;Tds=8.0;PrepareSql=3;XaEmulation=false
```

I've read conflicting posts as to whether I need

```
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

or not.  If I put the line between `println("1.")` and `println("2.")`, it just fails earlier with

```
1.
Error - net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

I may be missing something obvious, but please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Tried that thanks @Arvind, but got exactly the same No suitable driver error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be facing two issues:

**Issue 1.** It seems that jTDS 1.2 is sufficiently old that you actually do need to call

```java
Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
```

before you try to establish the connection.

**Issue 2.** When you specify the classpath, you need to explicitly include the jTDS jar file. That is, this won't work ...

```
C:\JavaTest>"\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe" -cp C:/JavaTest Example
1.
Error - net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
```

... but this works for me:

```
C:\JavaTest>"\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\java.exe" -cp C:/JavaTest;C:/JavaTest/jtds-1.2.jar Example
1.
2.
3.
Connected.
...
```

Comment: That's it @Gord Thompson!  The 'old' JTDS driver is a pain.  My objective is to get it to connect via an SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Listener...  I was also wrongly assuming the `-cp C:\JavaTest` would 'see' the .jar file within it.  Not supposed to say thanks in a Comment, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lets break down steps, run following commands from cmd:

```
cd C:\JavaTest
set path=C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin
javac example.java
java -cp .;jtds-1.2.jar -Djdbc.drivers=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver Example
```

The last line will load the driver manually, so no need to change code.

Problem is that you need to register driver before making connections to database.

> I've read conflicting posts as to whether I need

`Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");`

Yes, but you have to place it before line

`Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);`

Comment: Do not use the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. Use the `-cp` parameter for the `java` command

Comment: @Arvind - still same "Error - No suitable driver found for jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://UK-SB-SQL0..."